# how to insert a description in wordpress gallery popup?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, popup

I am using WordPress 4.2.2 and i need to show the image description in a gallery popup, like a light box view. In the gallery if i click a images i need to show the descriptions in a popup. In that popup i can edit the description and save to database and show the updated description in the same popup. I using the enfold theme currently. Is it possible to make this? Is there any plugins or can any one guide me to write it. Bellow i have given the example popup of gallery. Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin, It provides a powerful engine for uploading and managing galleries of images, with the ability to batch upload, import meta data, add/delete/rearrange/sort images, edit thumbnails, group galleries into albums, and more

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/
```

Comment: In a wordpress pages used to create a gallery and show in my site. In that ,when i click on the image i need to show the particular image description in popup. And the same popup i need to edit the description and update to database. This is my need, but i think this plugin only for show images right?